# Trying to register my Xamarin.iOS app to launch when custom document extension is opened or tapped

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uti, ios-sharesheet

Trying to achieve the same functionality as an Excel page that is shared or a Word doc that is shared opens the Excel or Word app.

I have a document with a custom extension .DLMSFT and .dlmsft. They are both registered in my app's **Document type**, **Exported Type Identifiers** and **Imported Type Identifiers**

See plist below:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Routes</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.Routes</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Routes</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.Routes</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>dlmsft</string>
                    <string>DLMSFT</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>

    <key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Routes</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.Routes</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>dlmsft</string>
                    <string>DLMSFT</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

**Expected Output** - To share via iOS Share Sheet to something like ***Teams*** or ***Slack*** or ***Outlook*** and when the receiving user opens the file it will open the app automatically **IF** they have it installed.

**Current Output** - I am able to share the file to all available apps including mail and outlook however when I share to MS Teams and the user on the receiving end opens it the app is not launched and instead they get an error that says "Teams cannot open the file as its unsupported". The same happens in Outlook. iOS Mail app is the only one that even allows you to choose the app to open the file.

For more context below is the code for sharing the document using the Share Sheet:

```
public static async void ShareRoute(Route route)
        {
            var routeTitle = $"{route.Start.Name}-To-{route.Destination.Name}.DLMSFT";

            var fn = routeTitle;
            var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
            File.WriteAllText(file, SerializeRoute(route));

            await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
            {
                Title = routeTitle,
                File = new ShareFile(file)
            });
        }
```

I feel like I have read docs after docs after docs and I also think I am following all the correct steps. Not sure what I am missing. Hopefully someone can lend a helping hand. Thanks all!

Comment: Mail being dimmed is not causing your problem. It is always dimmed because it should always be available.

You cannot choose Microsoft Outlook because Microsoft has not created a sharing extension for Outlook. They did so for OneNote, so they appear to be capable.

If you are using Outlook as your email client and don't have any accounts set up in Mail, I would assume that it wouldn't offer Mail as there would be no way to send anything with Mail. Check https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250400044

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your reply first off! My native iOS mail app is not dimmed. Apologies for the confusion. My native mail app is actually the only app that allows my app to open my custom extension. 
What Im trying to go for is to share my doc with MSTeams, Outlook, Slack etc...and have it open my app by default when the user taps on it.

Comment: That's because  iOS mail app had created the sharing extension .